# Using ES6 Proxy with PhantomJS

Tags: proxy, phantomjs, ecmascript-6

My code uses ES6 Proxy class. When run with PhantomJS (v 2.1.1) Proxy class is not found. I tried using harmony-reflect, but that doesn't work either. It says `proxies not supported on this platform. On v8/node/iojs, make sure to pass the --harmony_proxies flag`. Would anyone have a clue how to make it work (hopefully not involving the use of Babel)?

Comment: (Babel wouldn't help, Proxy can't be polyfilled.)

Comment: What PhantomJS uses - navigator.appVersions says "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1". That seems to be somewhere around Safari 7/8 and doesn't have Proxy class.

Comment: That's not the JavaScript engine, that's the "browser" (which is PhantomJS itself). But ignore the question, I forgot that PhantomJS has a JS engine built in.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS uses JavaScriptCore, which is the default JavaScript engine for WebKit and part of the WebKit project.

JSC doesn't support `Proxy` yet; it's [on the list](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35731) and it looks like someone's been assigned to it at least since February.

Since `Proxy` can't be polyfilled, you won't be able to use PhantomJS to run `Proxy` code until JSC supports `Proxy` and an updated PhantomJS is built against that updated JSC.

Comment: This.. is surprising. If i might overreact and state, this makes PhatomJS completely unreliable and unusable. Very big sad face. I had thought it would use the Node runtime and build phantom DOM. And how is WebKit so far behind?